# Is there a way to associate a symbol style file .sld to a geojson file with QGIS

Tags: styles, geojson, symbols, qgis, sld

I have a **QGIS** project and i would like to export a point **Geojson** file with styles.
The given style is a **symbol** for each point.
I can generate **.sld** file but the Application i am working with takes only Gesojson as its input.

Comment: Which 'Application' are you using to display the geoJSON file?